# How to mix JPA and JDBCTemplate because of Hibernate @Formula bug

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Hibernate through Spring Data JPA and trying to add a calculated field. A simple `SELECT 1*1` query works, but when I add the real formula, Hibernate gets totally confused and generates a syntactically invalid query.

Parent table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "szallitolevel")
public class Szallitolevel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Min(1)
    private Long szam;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private Partner partner;

    @Formula("(select sum(xx.mennyiseg) from szallitolevel_sor xx where xx.szallitolevel = id)")
//    @Formula("(select 1*1)")
    private Long sumMennyiseg;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="szallitolevel", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval=true)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @Valid
    private List<SzallitolevelSor> sorok = new AutoPopulatingList<SzallitolevelSor>(SzallitolevelSor.class);
}
```

Child table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "szallitolevel_sor")
public class SzallitolevelSor {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String nev;

    @Min(0)
    private Long mennyiseg;

    @ManyToOne
    private Szallitolevel szallitolevel;
}
```

There is not even a sum() in the generated query, and the formula somehow found its way to the WHERE part:

```
select 
  sorok0_.szallitolevel as szallito4_2_1_, 
  sorok0_.id as id1_3_1_, 
  sorok0_.id as id1_3_0_,
  sorok0_.mennyiseg as mennyise2_3_0_, 
  sorok0_.nev as nev3_3_0_, 
  sorok0_.szallitolevel as szallito4_3_0_ 
from szallitolevel_sor sorok0_ 
where sorok0_.szallitolevel 
  in (select szallitole0_.id 
      from szallitolevel_sor xx 
      where xx.szallitolevel = szallitole0_.id) as formula0_0_,
        partner1_.nev as nev2_1_1_, 
        partner1_.penz as penz3_1_1_ 
from szallitolevel szallitole0_ 
  left outer join partner partner1_ 
    on szallitole0_.partner=partner1_.id) 

 {FAILED after 0 msec}
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as formula0_0_, partner1_.nev as nev2_1_1_, partner1_.penz as penz3_1_1_ from sz' at line 1
```

**UPDATE**: I'm using JDBCTemplate for the relevant query, see answer

Comment: I tried to structure the SQL a bit. It actually doesn't really work.

Comment: I seems to try to be smarter than it is.

Comment: Well, this was the last straw for me. JPA looks useful until I try to apply it to real-world tasks. I spent the last 3 days solving problem after problem instead of making progress. Moving back to JDBCTemplate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So finally I decided to try to keep JPA for simple CRUD and allow a JDBC escape path if it takes more than 10 minutes to make something work with JPA. Using JDBC for the above problem requires the following steps:

Create a JDBCTemplate bean in one of the config classes:

```
@Bean
public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}
```

Set calculated entity field transient so Hibernate ignores it. Also make sure there is a getter and a setter:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "szallitolevel")
public class Szallitolevel {
    ...
    @Transient
    private Long sumMennyiseg = 0L;
    ...
}
```

Customize the JPA repository (you can also see a fix here for the Hibernate N+1 problem by providing a custom query to `findAll`):

```
public interface SzallitolevelRepoCustom {
    List<Szallitolevel> customFindAll();
}


public interface SzallitolevelRepo extends CrudRepository<Szallitolevel, Long>, SzallitolevelRepoCustom {
    @Query("select s from Szallitolevel s left join fetch s.partner p")
    List<Szallitolevel> findAll();
}


public class SzallitolevelRepoImpl implements SzallitolevelRepoCustom {
    private static final String FIND_ALL = "SELECT sz.id, sum(sor.mennyiseg) as sumMennyiseg, partner.nev as 'partner.nev' "
            + "from szallitolevel sz "
            + "left join szallitolevel_sor sor on sor.szallitolevel = sz.id "
            + "left join partner on partner.id = sz.partner "
            + "group by sz.id ";

    @Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Override
    public List<Szallitolevel> customFindAll() {
        List<Szallitolevel> result = jdbcTemplate.query(FIND_ALL, new NestedRowMapper<>(Szallitolevel.class));
        return result;
    }
}
```

Note the alias `partner.nev` in the SQL. The row mapper will use this to create an empty Partner object and set only the `nev` property. (If you need the entire object filled and don't mind another DB query, you can also write a Spring converter from Long to Partner that retrieves the entire object from the database.)

Stole `NestedRowMapper` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31592035/1129486).