# Jdbc Template set List Object properties with row mapper

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jdbctemplate

I was reading this post : 
[JDBCTemplate set nested POJO with BeanPropertyRowMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718163/jdbctemplate-set-nested-pojo-with-beanpropertyrowmapper)

This answer seems great  : [JDBCTemplate set nested POJO with BeanPropertyRowMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718163/jdbctemplate-set-nested-pojo-with-beanpropertyrowmapper#answer-16730656) 
 However another situation came to my mind and I was not able until now to find suitable answer : 
  What if I got a list of Users in my message Class instead :

```
class User {
   Long id;
   String name;
}

class Message {
   Long id;
   String name;
   List<User> users;
}
```

Could it be even possible with sql request manually (no jpa or crud repository) and row mapper to map every User for One Message and to make something like ? :

```
public class MessageMapper implements RowMapper<Message> {

public Message mapRow(ResultSet rs, int i) throws SQLException{
   Message message= new Message();
   message.setId(rs.getLong("messageId");
   message.setName(rs.getString("messageName"));
   User user = new User();
   // or List<User> users = new ArrayList<>(); ??? ...
     user.setUsers(users);
   return message ;
  }}
```

Thank you !

Comment: Did you give a look to the `org.springframework.jdbc.core.ResultSetExtractor<T>` interface and to its `org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor<T>` implementation?

Comment: yes, but I don't understand what's your purpose ?

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: Start by writing the query returning messages and their users. Execute it, and see what each row contains. Then think about your question and ask yourself: does each row represents a message with all its users?

Comment: @JBNizet Sorry for late. Well, I understand it seems impossible.. My first idea was sql query like (not tried, I was just thinking about ): `select m.id as messageId, m.name as messageName,
array_agg(distinct(m.name||':'||u.name)) as messageAndUsers
 from message m 
left join user_message um on um.message_id=m.id
left join user u on u.id=um.user_id
where m.id=1
group by m.id`    But I guess concatenate like that and use it with RowMapper is not possible. Thank you though!